# C# - write a file that supports double byte characters

Tags: c#, csv

I have inherited an app that has been outputting a CSV file for years without issue. However, we now need it to support double-byte characters.

How do I set what character set the file should use (UTF-8 or whatever)?

I haven't used Visual Studio and C# in a few years and a lot has changed...

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: "Double-byte characters" doesn't mean much - I'd take it to mean UCS-2 or UTF-16, but there are other MBCS systems out there. We need to know exactly what the requirements are.

Comment: That said, use `System.Text.Encoding` to use any encoding system supported by your computer, including UCS-2 and UTF-16.

Comment: ^^ that. and it hasn't changed *in a few years* ;)

Comment: this has nothing to do with visual studio. share your code and where you are having problems.

Comment: One thing to watch out for if you use UTF-something is that a [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) may be present at the beginning of the file. You have to check that the program using the CSV file will work ok with that, or take steps to omit it.

Comment: I think it was just a matter of setting encoding.  File.WriteAllText(exportFilenameWithPath, sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: The file is being output to a third party vendor.  They are on holiday so I can't check with them at the moment.  Thanks for all of the quick replies!

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your title to remove 'Visual Studio' - VS is the IDE; the question would be the same if you were using notepad and compiling directly using MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.

encoding. File.WriteAllText(exportFilenameWithPath, sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);

worked perfectly.